# d3.hexbin data points not being displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The following snippet is basically this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4248145 but with custom data points. No matter how I scale or modify my points array, the hexagons are always at the upper left corner, though it seems that the distribution is displayed correctly.

How can I fix this?

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var points = [[1,1]]
        var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "#5B85AA"))
        .domain([0, 3]);
        
        var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
        .radius(20)
        .size([0, 3]);
        
        
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 4])
        .range([0, width]);
        
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 4])
        .range([height, 0]);
        
        g.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
        
        g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "hexagon")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(hexbin(points))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")"; })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
          return i * 10;
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected result, since your data is just:

```
[1, 1]
```

Which is a single data point next to the origin. For instance, using the same code but creating 1000 random data points from 0 to the `width`...

```
var points = d3.range(1000).map(d=>([Math.random()*width, Math.random()*width]));
```

... will have a different result:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var points = d3.range(1000).map(d=>([Math.random()*width, Math.random()*width]));
        var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "#5B85AA"))
        .domain([0, 3]);
        
        var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
        .radius(20)
        .size([0, 3]);
        
        
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 4])
        .range([0, width]);
        
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 4])
        .range([height, 0]);
        
        g.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
        
        g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "hexagon")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(hexbin(points))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")"; })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
          return i * 10;
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Besides that, what you said:

> No matter how I scale or modify my points array, the hexagons are always at the upper left corner.

Is not accurate. For instance, this is the same code, but using `[[100,100]]`. You can see the hexagon further down and to the right:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var points = [[100,100]];
        var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("white", "#5B85AA"))
        .domain([0, 3]);
        
        var hexbin = d3.hexbin()
        .radius(20)
        .size([0, 3]);
        
        
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 4])
        .range([0, width]);
        
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 4])
        .range([height, 0]);
        
        g.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
        
        g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "hexagon")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(hexbin(points))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", hexbin.hexagon())
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")"; })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
          return i * 10;
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think I see the problem now, my values are all very low and I need to scale the values to the width and height of the box.